# Percent reduction between two groups

Tags: t-test

We'd like to express how much better A performs when combined with B. Is it as simple as comparing the averages of the two groups?

When tested, widget A has a range of results from 36 to 43 with an AVG of 40(x).
When widget B is tested together with product A, the results have a range of 27 to 34 and an average of 30(y).

If tested a lot, the tails might rarely overlap.

0 good
44 bad. *very bad.*

```
 A)  0  .................|..|.||||||...|.  44
 AB) 0  ....|.|||||||.|..................  44
```

What's the best way to calculate and represent the data? Simple would be nice (i.e. "B makes A 10% Better!")

Current thinking is:
Percent Reduction =(x-y)/x

Comment: Are 'widget A' and 'product A' the same thing or different things? When you say 'tested together with' what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You really have two questions tied up together.

To answer the first (and easiest) the difference in the means is the difference in their performance.

The second, implicit, question is to what degree is this difference statistically significant.

The answer to that question involves [Statistical hypothesis testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing).

For your purposes, if you are testing a large enough sample that the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) holds or if you know that the population is [normally distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) then the [Student's t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test) is probably the most straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you can use a simple A/B Testing significance test (lots of those online). Those will show you the difference between average values and certainty with which the test group is better than control group (or whatever you label them).

If you really want to go into it, then I strongly recommend this blog post: [How large should your A/B test sample size be?](http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/split-testing-blog/how-to-calculate-ab-test-sample-size/) for understanding of how to set up tests and interpret the data properly; and this one: [What you really need to know about mathematics of A/B split testing](http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/split-testing-blog/what-you-really-need-to-know-about-mathematics-of-ab-split-testing/) for some basic math behind.

I urge you to firstly understand the concept of A/B testing and setting it up properly before actually going any further. The set up for both variations should be equivalent (best way to do it is to have both variations showing randomly for different users), that is eliminating the possibility that one had better exposure than another or daily/weekly fluctuations effect (i.e., if one was tested on Sunday, another on Monday - of course they'll be different).

In this particular case of yours, you need not only average, but uncertainty in its value as well. Average doesn't make sense until you know the precision of your estimate. That is, test results can be represented as (be careful if your data is far from normally distributed - check if it is first):

```
Variation A: AVG(a) ± STD(a)
Variation B: AVG(b) ± STD(b)
Difference: d ± unc(d)
```

Here `STD()` is standard deviation, `d = AVG(b) - AVG(a)` is difference between the groups and `unc(d) = SQRT(STD(a)^2 + STD(b)^2)` is uncertainty in this difference. This uncertainty is crucial as it tells you that you can't distinguish any difference smaller than `unc(d)` (roughly speaking).

So, when you actually calculate all the numbers you'll get something like: difference is `-10±3`, which would mean that with high certainty A is better than B and difference is likely to be larger than 7. To dig into the actual confidence intervals go to [Standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) article on Wikipedia, where it's well explained. I.e., for important tests it is recommended to use two standard deviation intervals (just multiply the uncertainty by 2) to have a strong case supporting the test result (in such case if the difference with its uncertainty interval doesn't overlap with 0, confidence would be ~95%).

(also looking at your case, my Variation B would be equivalent to what you call A combined with B)

Comment: Thank you both for the very thoughtful and helpful answers. I really appreciate it and will follow through on the suggested reading.